# Use variable in php array

Tags: arrays, variables

I have this code:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($sqlnews,'SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC');
$count = 0;
while($count < 4 && $output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
      $count++;
      echo '<div class="item"><div class="testimonials-box"><div class="testimonial-details"><h1><a class="news_subject" href="news.php?newsid='.$output['id'].'">'.$output['subject_en'].'</a></h1><br />';
      echo '<span class="news_author">'.$output['postedby'].'</span><b> | </b>';
      echo '<span class="news_date">'.date('l, d F Y', strtotime($output['date'])).'</span><div class="devider"></div>';
      echo '<span class="news_short">'.$output['short_description_en'].'</span></div></div>';
      echo '</div>'; 
}
?>
```

I wanna get the variable `$output` using array from another variable that also has an array, like this: `$output['$id["1"]']`
I get an error when trying to do this that says: `Undefined index: $id["1"] in`.
Notice that the array from `$id` is from antoher php file that is included in this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the apostrophes around `$id["1"]`:

```
$output[$id["1"]]
```

Otherwise, the `'$id["1"]'` is treated literally as a string index.

Comment: Okay, this works! But i have the array in another file and it says me that it's not defined.

Comment: No, my fault, i had the array like "'id'", and it has to be like "id" without the ''. Thanks a lot!